Conditional labeling for a bar chart?
Percentages <5% are overlapping in my bar chart and make the chart difficult to read. Is there a way to set a condition to suppress percentages below a certain threshold (e.g. < 5%)?
I used the below code to create a stacked bar chart. Everything is fine except that the data labels for the small percentages on the left side are overlapping. I've tried re-sizing the text, but the text becomes too small to read by the time the data labels no longer overlap.
Is there a way to suppress data labels that are <5% ?
I've also tried adding "plot.percents.low = FALSE" and "plot.percents.high = TRUE" to no avail.
Chart section
`p <- plot(likert(MyData), type = "bar",
      col = myColor, ordered = TRUE,  text.size = 5,  plot.percents = TRUE)`

`p <- p + ggtitle("Chart Title", subtitle = "Chart Subtitle")`
`p <- p + theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 25, face = "bold"),
           plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "italic"),
           axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", color = "black"),
           axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", color = "black"),
           axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
           panel.border = element_blank(),
           panel.background = element_blank(),
           legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
           legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"),
           legend.title = element_blank(),
           axis.line.y = element_line(color = "grey"),
           axis.line.x = element_blank())` 

`plot(p)`

